# Do light colored computers generate less heat

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, colors, cooling

I know that anything black absorbs heat while anything white reflects heat.So my HP Pavilion g7 2269wm (recently cleaned) is black and heats up-to 88C, but I have a light grey Sony VAIO VGN-NR120E and it only heats up-to 78C.So the white color VAIO with a dusty fan and dried thermal heats up less ? Also I aren't newer CPUs more power efficient

The motherboard of the VAIO is blue while the g7 is green.Has anyone had both a black and white of the exact same laptop and what are the results ?

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges, and then asking us if the colour of the fruit makes one grow better than the other.  The amount that the colour of these components would effect the reflection of heat from them would be negligible at best, and would have even less influence on over-all system heat in comparison to the design and component differences in the notebooks.

Comment: the only way this could make any difference is if you were using the laptops in direct sunlight, and even then, you might not notice a huge difference

Answer (score 1):

> Do light colored computers generate less heat.

Nope. In both cases the case does not generate any heat at all.

> Also I aren't newer CPUs more power efficient

Yes, most of the time. But that does not mean that they produce less heat.

This will be the case moust of the time, but a counter example would be a CPU which is more efficient per core but adds many more cores.

E.g.
 old: 2 core, old_efficiency
 new: 8 core, slightly more efficient.

Just being newer can be used as a guideline only.

Comment: The newer laptop has a 1.9Ghz up-to 2.8Ghz quad core CPU while the VAIO has a 1.4Ghz dual core CPU

Comment: @SuiciDoga if you want to get more exact comparison: check the processor datasheet page eg. ark.intel.com and look for `TDP` entry for your model - that is the heat this processor will produce at maximum speed.

Comment: @SuiciDoga also i feel like this should be mentioned too: It is true that black colored surfaces - specifically matt ones - are best in absorbing heat, however this goes both ways - so they are best in radiating heat as well (that's why on computer components or in car radiators are painted black). Still computer case doesn't matter here, the fan and heat pipe system inside does.

Comment: They are both 35 TDP.I ran Prime95 at 1.4Ghz on the g7 and it doesn't go above 68C (at normal speed it reaches 88C) , so the efficiency has improved.And the g7's fan is also black color with some black paint on part of the heatsink and also it is a glossy black color

Comment: @SuiciDoga since they both have TDP rated 35 Watts, then this means that the pavillion computer has less effective CPU cooling. In laptops majority of heat from CPU gets transferred in conduction and convection. Color has effect only in radiation heat transfer. This is more important in passive-cooled components when new air isn't constantly blown on the cooler surface. What i'm guessing is, that the pavilion PC is worse in transfer of the heat from CPU board to the cooler attached to fan. Only case when laptop color could matter is when it's standing in strong direct sunlight.

Comment: Maybe it could be the heat transfer since HP is known to overheat and people mod them to fix the problems